# Replace rows with 0s in dataframe with preceding row values diverse than 0

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements, rows

Here an example of my dataframe:

```
df = read.table(text = 'a  b
120 5
120 5
120 5
119 0
118 0
88 3
88 3
87 0  
10 3
10 3
10 3
7 4
6 0
5 0
4 0', header = TRUE)
```

I need to replace the 0s within col `b` with each preceding number diverse than 0.

Here my desired output:

```
 a  b
120 5
120 5
120 5
119 5
118 5
88 3
88 3
87 3  
10 3
10 3
10 3
7 4
6 4
5 4
4 4
```

Until now I tried:

```
df$b[df$b == 0] = (df$b == 0) - 1
```

But it does not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`na.locf` from `zoo` can help with this:

```
library(zoo)
#converting zeros to NA so that na.locf can get them
df$b[df$b == 0] <- NA
#using na.locf to replace NA with previous value
df$b <- na.locf(df$b)
```

Out:

```
> df
     a b
1  120 5
2  120 5
3  120 5
4  119 5
5  118 5
6   88 3
7   88 3
8   87 3
9   10 3
10  10 3
11  10 3
12   7 4
13   6 4
14   5 4
15   4 4
```

Answer (score 5):

Performing this task in a simple condition seems pretty hard, but you could also use a small for loop instead of loading a package.

```
for (i in which(df$b==0)) {
  df$b[i] = df$b[i-1]
}
```

Output:

```
> df
     a b
1  120 5
2  120 5
3  120 5
4  119 5
5  118 5
6   88 3
7   88 3
8   87 3
9   10 3
10  10 3
11  10 3
12   7 4
13   6 4
14   5 4
15   4 4
```

I assume that this could be slow for large data.frames

Comment: For such tasks, the `cum*` functions could be worth some tries. E.g. here `df$b[cummax((df$b > 0) * (1:nrow(df)))]` seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R method using `rle`.

```
# get the run length encoding of variable
temp <- rle(df$b)
# fill in 0s with previous value
temp$values[temp$values == 0] <- temp$values[which(temp$values == 0) -1]
# replace variable
df$b <- inverse.rle(temp)
```

This returns

```
df
     a b
1  120 5
2  120 5
3  120 5
4  119 5
5  118 5
6   88 3
7   88 3
8   87 3
9   10 3
10  10 3
11  10 3
12   7 4
13   6 4
14   5 4
15   4 4
```

Note that the replacement line will throw an error if the first element of the vector is 0. You can fix this by creating a vector that excludes it.

For example

```
replacers <- which(temp$values == 0)
replacers <- replacers[replacers > 1]
```